# Unable to upgrade to Microsoft SQL Server2008 R2 RTM - Express with Advanced Services

Tags: upgrade, begininvoke, sql-server-2008r2-express

I am trying to upgrade my current Express edition to *Express with Advanced Services* for supporting full-text search.

The current system setup is:

- OS version: Windows server 2008 R2 web server 64 bit
- SQL Server 2008 R2 Express, SP1, v10.50.2500.0

I have downloaded the SQL Server with Advanced Services. I am unable to upgrade the edition. The installation step goes without any issues and even getting *Edition upgrade completed* page. But once I click the close this page, an error will pop up.

> SQL Server Setup has encountered the following error: Invoke or
>   BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has
>   been created.

Can some please assist me here to the right direction?

I could see that the version of SQL Server Express with Advanced Services is 10.50.1600.1. Is this the cause? So should I downgrade the sp1 to normal Express r2 edition before upgrading?

Downloaded link for the Express with advanced services http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=25174

Answer (score 5):

I got it working finally!!

I was getting the below error previously. It is a bug and is related to UI. So i have upgraded using the command line that too in QUIET mode to prevent any UI intervention.

"SQL Server Setup has encountered the following error:
Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created."

Following are the steps i used:-

1. Downloaded the latest sp1 for SQL Server 2008 r2 with Advanced Services (SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU.exe) from http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=26729
2. Extracted the SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU.exe to D:\SQL2008
3. Open command prompt as "Administrator"
4. Executed the following commands

   ```
   D:\sql2008\setup.exe /ACTION=editionupgrade /INSTANCENAME=MyInstance /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS  /FEATURES=SQL,RS  /INDICATEPROGRESS  /Q
   ```

*MyInstance is your sql server instance name

*/INDICATEPROGRESS  will show the setup progress to command prompt(For a confirmation :) )

You can follow this doc for more setup parameters
        http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144259(v=sql.105).aspx

1. Verified the upgrade has been successful.
2. Unfortunately FULL-TEXT Search feature was not enabled.
3. So Run the setup.exe as normall(double click) and added "FULL-TEXT Search" feature to the existing instance.

   Everything works fine now. Thank you all.

Comment: Good explanation of how you figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

I can verify that this bug and the same resolution also apply to SQL Server 2008 R2 Express **SP2** v10.50.4000.0